# user@0.service failed in WSL with systemctl enabled

Tags: systemd, wsl2

The `user@0.service` unit failed to start in my WSL system on my Windows machine. The error is because the `/run/user/0` directory belongs to my user account, not the **root**. I tried to change its owner to root, but it got changed back, and I think I should not touch those default system settings.

I wonder what I can do to fix this `user@0.service` unit. Can I disable it?

Comment: As I wrote in https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/9344, this seems to be caused by Docker Desktop for Windows.

Comment: I personally recommend switching to normal docker daemon on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

credits to @nonylene

This issue is caused by the WSL integration feature in Docker Desktop for Windows. This issue does not seem to cause any usability issues in the WSL environment.

You can resolve this issue by disabling the WSL integration feature. But you will loss access to your Docker engine from your WSL environment.